# Add authenticated user id by filter to java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have an authentication filter that authorize REST call by JWT Token. I already implemented the authentication through JWT and the JWT validation by a Filter. How can I pass the user id coming from the JWT to the servlet in the filter process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is done with an [HttpServletRequestWrapper](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html). It's an object that allows you to add or override methods on the standard `HttpServletRequest`.

Within your filter, wrap the original `HttpServletRequest` with your own `RequestWrapper` and then send your `RequestWrapper` to the servlet *instead* of the original `HttpServletRequest`.

For example, here's a simple `RequestWrapper` to pass an authenticated userId:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

public class AuthenticatedRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private int userId;

    public AuthenticatedRequest(HttpServletRequest req, int userId) {
        super(req);
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

}
```

Wrap the original request in your authentication filter before forwarding to your servlet chain:

```
// in filter class
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) 
    throws ServletException {

    int userId;

    // do something to get your authentication data (userId)
    // ...
    // wrap the original request with the "AuthenticatedRequest" 
    AuthenticatedRequest authRequest = new AuthenticatedRequest(req, userId);

    // forward the AuthenticatedRequest to the servlet
    chain.doFilter(authRequest, res);

}
```

The Servlet can then use your new wrapped request methods to access the auth data:

```
// in servlet class
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException
{
    // this request object is actually your own AuthenticatedRequest wrapper
    int userId = req.getUserId();
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44182370/1062992) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178257/add-http-basic-authentication-to-servletrequest) cover some more implementation details.

Comment: I love this solution. Thanks. I will use your approach.